# How to select second listbox

Tags: c++, listbox, gtk

I'm working on a project to select a specific file from a specific (USB) drive on a raspberry pi. These lists have to be navigated by gpio hardware (encoder, buttons). I have two listboxes. 1 containing the drive, the other containing the files on the selected drive. The only problem I seem to have is to switch from the drive list to the file list once the drive is selected.

To what I found in the reference guide I suspect this to work:

```
static void drive_selected(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data){
    gtk_list_box_select_row(GTK_LIST_BOX(data), gtk_list_box_get_row_at_index(GTK_LIST_BOX(data), 1));
}
```

But I always get This as a result:

```
(a.out:24969): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GtkListBoxRow' to 'GtkListBox'

(a.out:24969): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GtkListBoxRow' to 'GtkListBox'

(a.out:24969): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_list_box_get_row_at_index: assertion 'GTK_IS_LIST_BOX (box)' failed

(a.out:24969): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_list_box_select_row: assertion 'GTK_IS_LIST_BOX (box)' failed
```

And nothing gets selected.

Answer (score 0):

You're showing us a single line of code so I'm just guessing here...

Assuming  `drive_selected()` is a callback for "row-selected" signal, your function signature is wrong. It should be:

```
void drive_selected (GtkListBox *box, GtkListBoxRow *row, gpointer user_data)
```

Currently you're trying to use the second argument (ListBoxRow) as a ListBox.